# Conditional execution of mocha test cases

Tags: tdd, mocha.js

I am using Mocha with Sinon JS and Phantom Js to test the google analytics call from a particular page. Till now, i am able to execute static test cases for individual element by writing different test case for each element. Like :

```
describe("Site Home Page Test", function() {

    it ("Global Search track", function() {
        var link = $('button.search');
        link.click();
    });

});
```

Now the ask is, is it possible to execute test case if only $('elem') is found? something like this:

```
describe("Site Home Page Test", function() {

  //  if(condition) {

        it ("Global Search track", function() {
            var link = $('button.search');
            link.click();
        });

  //  }

});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've missed the question completly, but you can do conditional test cases exactly how you have it written:

```js
describe("Some module", function() {
    if(false) {
        it ("should NOT run this test case", function() { });
    }

    it("should run this test case", function() { });
});
```

[mocha](/questions/tagged/mocha) will only run the [unit-test](/questions/tagged/unit-test) that isn't in the if-statement.

```
Some module
  ✓ should run this test case 

1 passing (5 ms)
```

Comment: you are absolutely right Trevor. actually, i was putting the if condition inside the test case :( silly me ... but thanks man! for providing me inputs.

Comment: Can't we write two test cases one for correct condition/scenario and one for different one?